# How to restart automatically the application after clearing its storage?

Tags: android, storage, data-cleaning

I'm navigating to settings and manually clearing the app storage, after it my app was killing.

```
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS
        startActivity(intent)
```

how can I reopen my application after clearing the app storage?